# How can I access the pressure value of a cell in my problem and set it to zero in Ansys fluent using UDF?

Tags: c, user-defined-functions, fluent, ansys

I'm trying to define a function to loop over **every cell at every iteration** and check the pressure at that cell, and if the pressure is negative, then set the pressure at that cell to zero. How do I go about doing this?

Is this function correct?

```
#include "udf.h"

DEFINE_ADJUST(pressure_zero, d)
{
    cell_t c;
    Thread *c_thread;
    begin_c_loop(c, c_thread)
        {
            if (C_P(c, c_thread) < 0)
            {
                   C_P(c, c_thread) = 0; 
            }
        }
    }
    end_c_loop(c, c_thread)
}
```

Comment: Please provide a code sample of what you tried so far, so we can help you. We cant guess how you store your cells and their related pressure.

Comment: Hey, I just added my code.